# Font-Awesome icons shows up but

Tags: font-awesome

I have a question about Font Awesome. I'm working on a school project, using the codes from codrops [Split Layout](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/10/25/split-layout/). Until this point, I have replaced the code's broken font types with "Font Awesome". On my local computer, I've managed to make it work. Here are pictures of how it looks in 2 frames.

This first picture is without hoving over anything. All objects are fine and visible:

[image]

In my second picture, it shows how it looks when I hover on any button:

[image]

These pictures are taken on my computer. Until I uploaded them, it was all good. Whenever I have uploaded my files to web, I've seen these two pictures. One with no hover ( http://tinypic.com/m/i6ijix/4 ) and with hover on ( http://tinypic.com/m/i6ijj6/4 ).

On second set of pictures there are some shapes that appeared after uploading the files to web host and when I hover on them, the buttons misplace but not on the first two pictures. Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is based within the files, try to reupload them. What's your html markup? 
I had this problem with Glyphs over 10 times, file uploader was corrupting them and I had to use other FTP client.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, they are html5. I am using Filezilla as ftp manager.